# Как изменить String в C#

Tags: c#, строки

Например, у меня есть путь к файлу

`string InputPath = @"C:\Users\Vardan\Desktop\Test\Input.txt"`

Я хочу, создать новый string и поменять последную часть на

`string ResultPath = @"C:\Users\Vardan\Desktop\Test\Result.txt"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для работы с путями в шарпе есть Path. Остальное - костыли которые будут ломаться в той или иной ситуации, потому что программист что-то да забудет учесть.

Поэтому как-то так:

```
var oldPath = @"C:\Users\Vardan\Desktop\Test\Input.txt";

var tmp = new[] { Path.GetDirectoryName(oldPath), "Result.txt" };

var newPath = Path.Combine(tmp);
```

Цитата из документации:

> GetDirectoryName('C:\MyDir\MySubDir\myfile.ext') returns 'C:\MyDir\MySubDir'

Comment: если уж используешь `Path`, то стоит везде его использовать, например [`.Combine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0), а не сложение строк

Comment: @Grundy согласен, спасибо за исправление

Comment: А зачем массив? Там же есть перегрузка [Combine(String, String)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0#System_IO_Path_Combine_System_String_System_String_)

Comment: @Grundy мне показалось что так читабельнее чем пихать вызов функции в друю функцию.

Comment: А, в этом смысле - может быть

Answer (score 3):

```cs
string ReplaceFileName(string path, string newFileName)
{
    var fileNameStart = Math.Max(path.LastIndexOf('\\'), path.LastIndexOf('/')) + 1;

    return path.Remove(fileNameStart) + newFileName;
}
```

`path` *должен* быть валиден.

---

Или в "1" строчку:

```cs
string ReplaceFileName(string path, string newFileName) =>
    path.Remove(Math.Max(path.LastIndexOf('\\'), path.LastIndexOf('/')) + 1) +
    newFileName;
```

---

Алгоритм основан на том, что имя файла начинается после *последнего* разделителя. Мы его ищем, а затем добавляем `1` (сразу за разделителем идет начало нашего имени файла). Дальше, зная строку, которую нужно заменить, заменяем её.